# Accessing the variables from a PHP Anonymous Function

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have the following class with static variables. How can I access the static functions of a class from within an anonymous PHP function?

```
class MyClass {
  public static function MyFunction(mylocalparam){
      MyStaticClass:MyStaticMethod(function(myparam) use(mylocalparam){
         MyClass::MyFunction2(mylocalparam);
   });
  }

  private static function MyFunction2(someobject){
  }
}
```

I am having trouble accessing the function "MyFunction2" from within the anonymous class. Could you please advice on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going to happen. You need to make the static function `public`. The anonymous function doesn't run inside the scope of `MyClass`, and therefore doesn't have access to `private` methods contained within it.

Answer (score 1):

Statically is not possible, but if you want you can pass the method you want to call via parameter as of type `callback`.

If you change the entire class to be an instance class (deleting all the `static` keywords) then you can use `$this` inside the anonymous function to call any method of the class you are in.

From the PHP manual:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope.

As specified:

> In version 5.4.0 $this can be used in anonymous functions.

```
class MyClass {
  public function MyFunction($mylocalparam){
      MyStaticClass:MyStaticMethod(function($myparam) use($mylocalparam){
         $this->MyFunction2($mylocalparam);
   });
  }

  private function MyFunction2($someobject){
  }
}
```